# WFS request with CQL_Filter projection

Tags: geoserver, coordinate-system, wfs, cql-filter

I have a layer in Geoserver called bln_blocks. The layer is in `EPSG:3857`.

I am doing the follwoing WFS request with a CQL Filter:

```
  var geoserverURL = geoserverURL + '/ows?';
  var service = 'service=WFS&';
  var version = 'version=1.1.0&';
  var request = 'request=GetFeature&';
  var typeName = 'typeName=' + layerName;
  var special = "&outputFormat=text/javascript&format_options=callback:getJson";
  var filter = '&CQL_FILTER=WITHIN%28geom%2C+POLYGON%28%281489248.8973085624165833+6895049.90960700158029795%2C1489248.8973085624165833+6895577.80283359717577696%2C1489945.19086309685371816+6895577.80283359717577696%2C1489945.19086309685371816+6895049.90960700158029795%2C1489248.8973085624165833+6895049.90960700158029795%29%29%29';
  var urlWFS = geoserverURL + service + version + request + typeName + filter +special;
```

The polygon in my CQL_Filter is also in `EPSG:3857`. Is it possible that I specify my polygon in `EPSG:4326`?

Comment: did you try the 'srsName' parameter explained [here](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wfs/vendor.html)?

Comment: The `srsName` parameter only reprojects the returned data, but not the input data of the CQL_Filter.

Comment: Another workaround to this problem is to reproject the Polygon to EPSG:4326 as described here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/103004/reproject-wkt-polygon-with-javascript/103112#103112

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know this is not supported. Ask from geoserver-users mailing list first and make a feature request to Geoserver jira because it feels like a useful addition. Meanwhile you can use the standard OGC filter instead

```xml
<Filter>
      <Intersects>
        <PropertyName>the_geom</PropertyName>
          <gml:Point srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#4326">
            <gml:coordinates>-74.817265,40.5296504</gml:coordinates>
          </gml:Point>
      </Intersects>
</Filter>
```

Using `FILTER` in HTTP GET requests is a bit tricky and ugly. You must URL-encode everything after the `&FILTER=` and you must probably also add some namespace definitions but by studying the following example it should be doable.

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?request=GetFeature&version=1.0.0&typeName=topp:states&outputFormat=GML2&FILTER=%3CFilter%20xmlns=%22http://www.opengis.net/ogc%22%20xmlns:gml=%22http://www.opengis.net/gml%22%3E%3CIntersects%3E%3CPropertyName%3Ethe_geom%3C/PropertyName%3E%3Cgml:Point%20srsName=%22EPSG:4326%22%3E%3Cgml:coordinates%3E-74.817265,40.5296504%3C/gml:coordinates%3E%3C/gml:Point%3E%3C/Intersects%3E%3C/Filter%3E
```